# What is the canonical reference on probabilistic data structures?

Tags: data-structures

I've heard of probabilistic data structures like [Skip Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) and [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) being immensely useful and I'd like to learn more about them in general. Is there a canonical reference on the subject on the level of Cormen et al.?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Theory-Computation-Handbook-Edition/dp/1584888180

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest site I can think of that might be canonical is
the NIST standards web site:

http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/skiplist.html

This site can be short on descriptions but has links to external
sites ..

Answer (score 6):

The best list that I could find, that has [probabilistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm) [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) is [this Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aProbabilistic_data_structures) The problem here is, the page also includes probabilistic algorithms. The list that I know of is:

- [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)
- [Random Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_tree) - This is a general term, and "umbrellas" many different structures.
- [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)
- [Treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap)

There are probably many more, but these are the ones that I have found or that I was aware of.